# transform-origins y-offset position when using calc()

Tags: css, transform, css-transforms

In this demo below, I am using `transform-origin` like this:

```
transform-origin: 50% calc(100% + 6em);
```

The y-offset value is set at `calc(100% + 6em)`, but what am I setting the value of the y-offset to? I can see that it is `+ 6em`, but `+ 6em` from where, exactly?

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: red;
  margin: 0 auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.me {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid #444;
  background: pink;
  margin: 20% auto;
  transition: 2s;
  transform: rotateZ(45deg);
  transform-origin: 50% calc(100% + 6em);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.container:hover .me {
  transform: rotateZ(0deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="me"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the `transform-origin` is given two values, like in your example, it is setting the x-offset and the y-offset, using the ["two-value syntax"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin#Syntax):

```
transform-origin: x-offset y-offset
```

The percentage value length is based on the element that the transform origin is set on.

- The **x-offset** begins at the left of the element. `50%` plots the x-offset position in the very middle of the element.
- The **y-offset** begins at the top of the element. `100% + 6em` plots the y-offset position at the bottom of the element *plus an extra 6 em*.

The x and y offset meet to form a single point, illustrated here where the two orange lines meet:

[image: Screenshot]

### Offset position — live example

In this example, the position of the offset is shown with the two pseudo elements.

You can change the two values of the before and after pseudo elements at the bottom of the CSS to easily show where the offset point location is. Change the values as shown in the CSS comments to plot the point visually.

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #000;
  margin: 0 auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
.container:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
.me {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: pink;
  transition: 2s;
  transform: rotateZ(45deg);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.me:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -5px;
  left: 0;
  background: #F90;
}
.me:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: -5px;
  background: #F90;
}
.container:hover .me {
  transform: rotateZ(0deg);
}
.me {
  /* x-offset | y-offset */
  transform-origin: 50% calc(100% + 6em);
}
.me:after {
  height: calc(100% + 6em); /* Set to y-offset value */
  left: 50%; /*  Set to x-offset value */
}
.me:before {
  width: 50%; /*   Set to x-offset value */
  top: calc(100% + 6em);  /*  Set to y-offset value */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="me"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Perfect ! now when u said "The y-offset begins at the top of the element and 100% + 6em plots the x-offset position at the bottom of the element + 6 em further below." did u actually mean "bottom right +6em" ??? Thanks Though ! that was of great help .

Comment: ! bottom right ? or bottom left ? sorry to ask too many questions lol

Comment: Oh, I see what you meant. The y-offset only deals with the y-axis position (top to bottom) The *x-offset* deals with the x-axis (left to right). The meet to form a single point. Does that make sense? 100% x-offset would push the point to the bottom right.

Comment: No worries! Once you can visualise what is going on it becomes a lot simpler :)